# What characters won't be in question->body?

Tags: support

This might seem kinda strange, but what printable ASCII characters am I guaranteed not to find in the `body` member of a question / answer?

Answer (score 2):

Its HTML.

So, those guaranteed not to be found in HTML.

Comment: I guess my question is "does StackOverflow add anything that *isn't* in the HTML spec?"

Comment: @George - of course not.